# Handling tables of different types in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design

I am designing a database for an ASP.NET MVC application.  I'm an expert in neither, and I'm curious what the best approach would be for the following database snippet:

We will be storing Events in our database.  Each event will be of a different type with various fields exclusive to one or some of the types.  An example:

```
Events
* Id
* EventTypeId
* AllEventTypes_Field

EventType0
* EventId (FK)
* EventType0_Field

EventType1
* EventId (FK)
* EventType1_Field
```

We'll have a handful of event types in the end.  I am tempted to put all fields into one large Events table, with nullable fields where appropriate.  Or, we can separate out the tables into Supertype/Subtype:  Events, EventType1, EventType2, etc (As above).

For the database design portion, I want to choose what makes the most sense and is "easiest" for the MVC framework.  Essentially:  what path will yield the least amount of headaches? :)

For super/sub types, would it be a matter of dragging over the Events table and creating classes for each subtype off of the main Events table?

Comment: Do you know if you're using Linq2SQL or Entity Framework for your database ORM objects? You should have selected one when you added it to your project.

Comment: LINQ.  Though honestly,  I can't say for sure how LINQ2SQL and EF differ.  Does it make a world of difference?  Sorry for the newboe reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Microsoft article discusses optional one-to-one relationships, which is essentially what you are describing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd326769(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, Robert.  I'm also looking for information on how LINQtoSQL and/or EF can handle what that article is talking about.

Comment: Creating classes in Linq to SQL or EF is a simple matter of dragging the tables over to the Linq to SQL designer from the Server Explorer. A one to one link should automatically be established between the classes. In your code, the link should be accessible like this: `MyEvent.EventType1.EventType1_Field`

Comment: Say I abandon the 1:1 link and have one large table.  Does it make sense to then break the table up into separate subtypes/LINQ classes?

I bring this up as there are some properties that exist on maybe 1/2 of the subtypes - so I'm tempted to just have one large database table, but have multiple classes in my data layer - feasible/possible?

Many thanks for the input, Robert :)

Comment: Unless you have separate tables I don't see anything to be gained by having separate classes.